# Hide Aria label with css or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, hide

I want to hide an arialabel without modifying it so just adding some code in css or javascript.
I know that you can put display:none for a class but is there any similar options for labels ?

Here's the aria label I want to hide. It doesn't have any ID

//  aria-label="Sign-up" href="/EN-CA/contact-sign-up/" title="Sign-up">
Sign-up
 //

Comment: Why would you want to hide that label? It's useful for screen readers. Do you just want to change the content of it or remove it?

Comment: Hi I want to hide it for a specific page

Comment: Also you need to be specific on whether its the label you want to hide, or the entire element containing that label.

Comment: It's the entire element thanks !

Comment: The CSS given at the top of my edited answer will do that. You just need to add in what element it is in the selector because you haven't mentioned that in the question

Comment: It's a menuitem the css is not working do you think i have to implement a function with js?

Comment: what is the element - is it a `<div>`, an anchor link `<a>`, a list item `<li>`?. You won't need JS if you want to hide the element, you just need to tell us what the HTML element is.

Comment: it's an <a> <a role="menuitem"
                    aria-label="Sign-up"
                                        href="/EN-CA/contact-sign-up/"
 title="Sign-up">
                      Sign-up
                </a>
so the css will be a[aria-label=Sign-up]?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` for this but if it isn't working for some reason, there's a way to hide aria-labels.

Use `aria-hidden="true"`.
For example, `<p aria-hidden="true">Hidden Aria Label</p>`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't add this to the code <p aria-hidden="true">Hidden Aria Label</p> I can only add css/html/javascript and refer to the code so i don't know how to do that if I don't have an ID , does signup{ display:none;} works with aria-label ?

Comment: it should work, yes.